# How to add columns to table using R

Tags: r

I have table A made using table()

```
Table A
   0    1    2    4 
2300   31    4    1
```

and

```
Table B
   0    1    2    3 
2123   31    4    1
```

I want to make plot from them but Table A is missing column with 3. I want to add column 3 to table A with 0 and column 4 to table B with 0.
Or maybe solution is with table, according to https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/table.html table() builds contingency table of the counts at each combination of factor levels. So when I don't have 3 occurances in my data it not shows in Table A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert to `factor` with `levels` specified for the 'A' and 'B' vectors.

```
table(factor(A, levels = 0:4))
table(factor(B, levels = 0:4))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
A <- sample(c(0, 1, 2, 4), 2500, replace = TRUE)
B <- sample(0:3, 2500, replace = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thx it worked, I made Table A from Named Int vector so I also had to use table(factor(unname(A), levels = 0:4))